# Why can't I set the initial capacity for a ConcurrentSkipListMap?

Tags: java, data-structures

Why doesn't the  [ConcurrentSkipListMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) constructors allow us to set the `initial capacity` like [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) does ?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik skiplist datastructures are new to me . I kind of require a sorted map implementation and that map will have to thrive concurrent modifications from multiple threads.Hence i was looking for ConcurrentSkipListmap > i have used Cocurrenthashmap before and used the intialCapacity so that rehashing doesn't ever happen .

Comment: @Geek - time to read a good data structures book.

Comment: @StephenC Reading Cormen et all but not yet gone to SkipLists . Covered uptill red Black trees.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because this data structure is backed by multiple [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) for whom an initial capacity constructor parameter has no meaning.

The HashMap is backed by an array (contiguous memory space) for which it makes sense to set an initial capacity because going over the initial size of this table cause the HashMap to reallocate a new table with an increased size which is very costly.

Comment: (But for HashMap, the flip-side is that it is also costly to significantly overestimate the size of the map ...)